# How to blit a PyQt screenshot to PyGame Window

Tags: python, pyqt, pygame

I have a program that is supposed to take screenshots...

```
#imports pyqt
from PyQt4.QtGui import QPixmap, QApplication

#declares variables
date = datetime.datetime.now()
counter = 0

#sets directory to be used to save screenshots
directorydate = str(date.year) + str(date.month) + str(date.day) + str(date.hour) +str(date.minute) + str(date.second)
directory = os.path.abspath('Photos%s' % directorydate)

#some weird PyQt thing I don't understand
app = QApplication(sys.argv)

#game loop
while True
counter += 1

#declarations
picdate = str(date.year) + str(date.month) + str(date.day) + str(date.hour) +str(date.minute) + str(date.second) + str(counter) + '.png'
pic = QPixmap.grabWindow(QApplication.desktop().winId())

#saves screenshots to a custom directory
pic.save('Photos%s/' % directorydate + picdate)

#adds screenshots to list and deletes them once 150 have been collected
if counter == 1:
    pics = [picdate]
    picfirst = pics[0]

    if not os.path.exists(directory):
        os.makedirs(directory)

else:
    pics.append(picdate)

if counter == 150:
    os.remove(picfirst)
    pics.remove(picfirst)
    counter = 0
```

...then animates them to the pygame window

```
background = pygame.image.load('Photos%s/' % directorydate + picdate)
displaysurf.blit(background)

#pygame event handling
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == QUIT:
        pygame.quit()
        sys.exit()

pygame.display.update()
```

When I try to run it, the shell gives me "error: Couldn't open Photos_____/____.png

I am not sure what the problem is as regardless of compatibility between PyGame and PyQt, once the image is saved as a .png, it should be able to be loaded like any other image. Is it just because it's open already while the code is running?

Any explanations and/or solutions would be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is that you first save pic with counter=1 without checking if directory exists so it's not saved at all.
After that you create directory if the pic counter == 1, so directory is created and all other pics will be saved in it but not first one.
You get error when you try to open that first pic which is not in the directory since it was not saved because directory has not existed.
Solution is to move this code:

```
if not os.path.exists(directory):
     os.makedirs(directory)
```

here:

```
#sets directory to be used to save screenshots
directorydate = str(date.year) + str(date.month) + str(date.day) + str(date.hour) +str(date.minute) + str(date.second)
directory = os.path.abspath('Photos%s' % directorydate)
if not os.path.exists(directory):
     os.makedirs(directory)
```